# Failed to resolve import?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, import

For some reason I'm getting a "Failed to resolve import" error message when trying to deploy to the Salesforce Sandbox. I have a another JS file with a function called "MapMarkers" in the "MapMarkers.js" file and want to import that function to the "mapping.js" file.
**What am I doing wrong when trying to import this function?**

[image]

**Here's my code and file location**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a typo in your `import` statement. In LWC, to import a function from another JavaScript file within the same component, you should use a relative path that starts with `./`

Here's the corrected import statement:

**mapping.js**

```
import { MapMarkers } from './MapMarkers';
```

Make sure, that you are exporting the function `MapMarkers` as well. In your current example, you are exporting named function.

**MapMarkers.js**

```
const MapMarkers = () {
    // some body here
}

export { MapMarkers };
```

---

Refer to [Share JavaScript Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_share_code)

> Create JavaScript files that export code in the same folder as the
> component importing the code. Import the code using a relative path.
> Other components can’t import this file directly. This approach
> supports structuring code within a component rather than sharing code
> with other components.

---

Community tip: don't use screenshots for a code in question, copy it as text.

Comment: Thank you it seems like it's importing correctly, as I am not getting the error anymore.

Comment: I have one more question the function I create isn't importing the mapMarkers data correctly. Should I be using a function for this or something else?

Comment: @Pinto If you have another problem - feel free to create a brand new question with all the needed details.

Comment: Ok will do, I'll create a new question. Thanks